# Create copyable code snippet for embedding in Rails and HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application where people can add submissions, and I want those submissions to be embeddable. I already have the API and the code, all that is missing is that under each submission there is a block that allows people to copy the full code for the embedding.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://untranslatable.co/api/embedded_submissions/1175"></script>
<div id="submission_1175"></div>
```

The only thing that needs to be adapted is the submission id (in this case above, 1175)

In an attempt to make the code copyable, I sanitized the html, but that means it won't read the Ruby code and it comes out like this

```
     &lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://untranslatable.co/api/embedded_submissions/#{submission.id}"&gt; &lt;/script&gt;
             &lt;div id="submission_#{submission.id}"&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
```

Comes out like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://untranslatable.co/api/embedded_submissions/#{submission.id}">
    <div id="#{submission.id}">
```

Any idea how I can create a copyable piece of code where the submission id is added in?

Comment: Please could you show your full code at the moment? Just saying "I sanitized the html" doesn't actually show us exactly what you've done, or might have done wrong.

Comment: I've included all the code I have at the moment. Maybe sanitized wasn't the right word, but I adapted the tags so the HTML item would show, as in this article. 

https://devpractical.com/display-html-tags-as-plain-text/#:~:text=You%20can%20show%20HTML%20tags,the%20reader%20on%20the%20browser

Comment: What's the context of the code beginning `&lt;script type=`? Is that a *raw HTML file*? (In which case, it should be no surprise that `#{submission.id}` isn't being interpolated with an actual value...) Or is it a template file, such as `haml`/`erb`/`slim`?

Comment: Are you aware that if your `<script>` tag wasn't sanitized but instead was added to the HTML with "correct" `<` chars instead of `&lt;` that then it would be no different from a default invisible script tag and it would just run the code in the context of the current page? The only option to have a show a visible and not evaluated script block on an HTML page is within a text area.

Comment: Okay, I don't think I am explaining myself well - yes, I am aware that what I am doing is making it impossible for the #{submission.id} to be interpolated, but I am not sure how else to show the html tag in a way that isn't being interpreted already.

Comment: That is exactly why I added the '&lt;' instead of the <, so that the code itself wouldn't just be embedding the submission, but instead, to show the code that could be copied and embedded in another page. 

I am still a beginner at Ruby, so there might be something very basic I am missing, but my question is - I have this code, how can I show it in a way that is both copyable and includes the submission.id